# regex with multiple line and grouping in c#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am struggling with a regex from below text

```
30T1 Error: NIO from  machine - sequence Nr. 1456
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 100
30T1 Warning: Stop at point not possible 
30T1 Error " 10" FS130 Machine stops working
30T1 Error " 331"  : Motor not working!
30T1 Error " 331"  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!
30T1 Error " 331"  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!
30T1 Warning: " 11" FS130  working
30T1 Error: NIO from machine - sequence Nr. 1356
30T1 Warning: Stop at point not possible 
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 110
30T1 Error " 331"  Machine: not available!
30T1 Error " 10" FS130  stops working
30T1 Error " 332"  Stud Machine Failure: current not available!
```

I would like to match an output like this and make a grouping

```
30T1 Error: NIO from  machine - sequence Nr. 1456
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 100
30T1 Error " 331"  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!

30T1 Error: NIO from machine - sequence Nr. 1356
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 110
30T1 Error " 332"  Stud Machine Failure: current not available!
```

until now i came up with the following regex which is working but it shows me only first line. I am unable to get the regex which can work for multiple line.

Regex Pattern what i tried unitl now:

```
(?<Error1>30T1\s+\w.+.?sequence\s+Nr.\s[0-9]+)
```

I am not expert with a regex i hope someone can enlighten me  to make better regex pattern.

Comment: Could you, please, be more exact about filtering and grouping? As I can see, you start new group on new *sequence* e.g. `sequence Nr. 1456`, `sequence Nr. 1356`. You filter out all *warnings*. But why do you skip some *errors*, e.g. `30T1 Error " 10" FS130 Machine stops working`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This information is not necessary for me that's why i skip this. the only thing i need as of now is the regex which can give me a desired output as above.

Comment: I see, but in order to write/amend the regex we have to know what to *include* and what to *exclude*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ok.. I got you what you ask for. 

    `machine - sequence Nr. 
    Stud machine point Nr.
    Stud Machine Failure `  The string contain above inormation i would like to inlcude and the rest not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggest using `IEnumerable<string>` and *Linq* instead of *regular expressions*

```
private static IEnumerable<string[]> ExtractLines(IEnumerable<string> source) {
  List<string> group = new List<string>();

  foreach (var line in source) {
    if (line.Contains("machine - sequence Nr.")) {
      if (group.Any())
        yield return group.ToArray();

      group.Clear();
      group.Add(line);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("Stud machine point Nr.") || 
             line.Contains("Stud Machine Failure"))
      if (!group.Contains(line)) // remove duplicates
        group.Add(line);
  }

  if (group.Any())
    yield return group.ToArray();
}

private static IEnumerable<String> MakeReport(IEnumerable<string> source) {
  bool firstLine = true;

  foreach (var group in ExtractLines(source)) {
    if (!firstLine)
      yield return "";

    firstLine = false;

    yield return (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, group));
  }
}
```

Test:

```
string text =
@"30T1 Error: NIO from  machine - sequence Nr. 1456
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 100
30T1 Warning: Stop at point not possible
30T1 Error "" 10"" FS130 Machine stops working
30T1 Error "" 331""  : Motor not working!
30T1 Error "" 331""  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!
30T1 Error "" 331""  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!
30T1 Warning: "" 11"" FS130 working
30T1 Error: NIO from machine - sequence Nr. 1356
30T1 Warning: Stop at point not possible
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 110
30T1 Error "" 331""  Machine: not available!
30T1 Error "" 10"" FS130 stops working
30T1 Error "" 332""  Stud Machine Failure: current not available!";

...

  var lines = text
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  var filtered = MakeReport(lines);

  foreach (var line in filtered) 
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Outcome:

```
30T1 Error: NIO from  machine - sequence Nr. 1456
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 100
30T1 Error " 331"  Stud Machine Failure: Motor not working!

30T1 Error: NIO from machine - sequence Nr. 1356
30T1 Error: Failure from Stud machine point Nr. 110
30T1 Error " 332"  Stud Machine Failure: current not available!
```

I guess you actually work with log *file*, in this case:

```
  var filtered = MakeReport(File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyLog.log"));

  foreach (var line in filtered) 
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but there is one problem in the line 
    `Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filtered));`
 It gives me an error Overloaded method match for string has invalid arguments. 
I have commet out the line and make breakpoint in make report method but the programm pointer never goes in that method. what is wrong with the code i didn't understand.

Comment: @user152117: It does work on my workstation, but let's get rid of `string.Join` and put it as `foreach`; please, see my edit.

Comment: that's works. But still I have some question.
1. I had assume that regex will work becuase i am working directly with the database. I was hoping that i can directly fetch the data using regex from database. Do you any better suggestion on this issue.